# Restsharp on WP 7.1 adding cookies

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, restsharp

I am trying to add a cookie to a request using RestSharp but in fiddler2 I don't see the cookie in the request and service call is failing.  Is there some trick to adding a cookie to the RestRequest?

```
 RestRequest rq = new RestRequest(LTV.NowNext(), Method.GET);
        rc.AddDefaultParameter(LTV.cookie.Key, LTV.cookie.Value, ParameterType.Cookie);

        rc.ExecuteAsync<LTV.nowNext>(rq, (response2) =>
        {
            if (response2.Data == null)
                return;
            foreach (LTV.channel channel in response2.Data.channels)
                this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = channel.name, LineTwo = channel.showing[0].content[0].parent.title, LineThree = channel.showing[1].content[0].parent.title });
        });
```

Thanks,
Al

Comment: Is this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557058/unable-to-send-cookies-with-restsharp-on-windows-phone?

Comment: Hmm, I've tested AddDefaultParameter and AddParameter and it works fine in fiddler.  What is LTV.NowNext() vs LTV.nowNext?

Comment: LTV.NowNext() is the URI path and LTV.nowNext is the resultant object - basically my bad and unimaginative naming structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestSharp has a bug on Windows Phone when adding cookies to the RestRequest!

I solved the issue and have a [pull request](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/215) waiting for them to integrate to the main branch.

For now, you can overcome this issue by using AddHeader("Cookie", cookieValuesString)...

Comment: Update: my fix has entered RestSharp main branch, so the next version has this issue fixed!