# Cookie Header Not Going Through In The Execution of GET Call

Tags: c#, restsharp, rest

Preface:

- This is a part of my personal project of building a control GUI for several communication devices - using WinForms unfortunately.
- The part of code running into trouble is rested inside the Constructor of a Form.
- Additional NuGet packages installed are:  Newtonsoft.Json, RestSharp, SpecFlow and SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic.
- **LoginForm** and **SeatsInfo** are two basic classes created only to store and organize my data, they have no additional coding besides properties declartions.

Execution code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CONTROL_UI
{
    public partial class RunningConfig : Form
    {
        public RunningConfig()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var client = new RestClient("CLIENT_URL");
            var loginRequest = new RestRequest("api/login", Method.POST);

            loginRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            loginRequest.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            loginRequest.AddJsonBody(new LoginForm() { username = "admin", password = "", @override = true });

            var loginRespone = client.Execute(loginRequest);

            JObject sessionInfo = JObject.Parse(loginRespone.Content);

            var sessionID = sessionInfo["sid"];

            var seatAvailRequest = new RestRequest("api/seats", Method.GET);

            seatAvailRequest.AddHeader("sid", sessionID.ToString());
            seatAvailRequest.AddHeader("Cookie", "sid = " + sessionID.ToString());

            var seatResponse = client.Execute(seatAvailRequest);

            List<SeatsInfo> seatsInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SeatsInfo>>(seatResponse.Content);

            //Further Implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Expected packet view in WireShark:
[image]

Actual packet view in WireShark:
[image]

sids are generated each time I successfully authorized to connect to the device, so they obviously differ.

The screenshot of my expected view is taken from the exact same block of codes in a plain console app. Everything works fine there. All the NuGet packages installed on the two programmes are of the same version, I even tried running them side-by-side but it did not help.

Debugging screenshots showed that the Parameters did, in fact, contain the Cookie header:
[image]

The header just did not go through for some reason. Would love to hear some thoughts in regards to this issue, many thanks in advance!

***Current solution, just add another AddCookie() method:***

```
            seatAvailRequest.AddHeader("sid", sessionID.ToString());
            seatAvailRequest.AddHeader("Cookie","sid = " + sessionID.ToString());
            seatAvailRequest.AddCookie("sid", sessionID.ToString());
```

This somehow does not work with just AddCookie() or AddHeader(), so for now they are both going in. Hope this helps someone, and thank yall for reading!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557058/unable-to-send-cookies-with-restsharp

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the post link. Though I did go through that one, did not help unfortunately. But I finally managed to figure it out, and already commented below. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in recap I was lacking the Cookie Header in the API call thus making the call being unsuccessful (the device did not authorized it).

After messing around with the AddCookie() method, particularly:

```
    seatAvailRequest.AddCookie("sid", sessionID.ToString());
```

The device gave me a different error - 404 Not Found, before was 401 Unauthorized:
[image]

Finally my dumb mind resorted using both the AddCookie() along with AddHeader() and voilà:
[image]

It works! Only after 5 hours of painful debugging and mind-numbing searches. Although the new packet is a bit larger, but I do not have to worry about that for now, or in the future realistically speaking.

Thanks you all for just following along, still open for suggestions and improvements!